# "Coin's" are not moving

Tags: python, pygame

So I been trying make my coin move -= its x value but it is not moving at all, I do not understand how it is only is working for my "Enemys," but it is not working for my coins. I have tried moving the code to all different spots also I have tried to copy the part were my "Enemys" are moving but that did not work.

This is what I wrote to make my coins move but it is not moving.

```
# Main Loop
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False



    for Coin in coins:
        Coin.x -= Coin.speed
```

This is my full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

# Build The Screen
window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))

# Name Screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs first Game")

bg = pygame.image.load("skybg1.png")
bg_shift = 0


# Class Player
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.speed = 6
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("heroplane1.png")
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//9,self.ss1.get_height()//9))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft=(self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        player_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        player_rect.centerx += -7
        player_rect.centery += -6
        window.blit(self.ss1,player_rect)

# Class Enemy
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color,imagefile):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.speed = 4
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load(imagefile)
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//9,self.ss1.get_height()//9))

        self.etimer = 0 # <---

    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)
        enemy_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        enemy_rect.centerx += -2
        enemy_rect.centery += -6
        window.blit(self.ss1,enemy_rect)


# Class Enemy2
class Enemy2:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color,imagefile):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.speed = 4
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load(imagefile)
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//9,self.ss1.get_height()//9))

        self.etimer = 0 # <---

    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)
        enemy_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        enemy_rect.centerx += -4
        enemy_rect.centery += -6
        window.blit(self.ss1,enemy_rect)


# Class Enemy3
class enemy3:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("enemyplane3.png")
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//9,self.ss1.get_height()//9))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        enemy3_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        enemy3_rect.centerx += -4
        enemy3_rect.centery += -6
        window.blit(self.ss1,enemy3_rect)



class projectile(object):
   def __init__(self, x, y,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.slash = pygame.image.load("herogun1.png")
       self.slash = pygame.transform.scale(self.slash,(self.slash.get_width()//11,self.slash.get_height()//11))
       self.rect  = self.slash.get_rect()
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x, self.y )
       self.speed = 10
       self.color = color

   def draw(self, window):
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x,self.y )
       window.blit(self.slash, self.rect)

class enemybullets(object):
   def __init__(self, x, y,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.slash = pygame.image.load("enemygun1.png")
       self.slash = pygame.transform.scale(self.slash,(self.slash.get_width()//11,self.slash.get_height()//11))
       self.rect  = self.slash.get_rect()
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x, self.y )
       self.speed = 10
       self.color = color

   def draw(self, window):
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x,self.y )
       window.blit(self.slash, self.rect)


class Coin:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 6
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("skycoin.png")
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//12,self.ss1.get_height()//12))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        coin_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        centery = -4
        ceterx = -4
        window.blit(self.ss1,self.rect)
    



        
# Color
white = (255,255,255)

# Draw Player
playerman = player(5,250,90,40,white)

# For Enemy
enemy1 = Enemy(400, 100, 90, 40, white, "enemyplane1.png")
enemy4 = Enemy(400, 400, 90, 40, white, "enemyplane1.png")

# For Enemy2
enemy21 = Enemy2(400,300,90,40,white,"enemyplane2.png")
enemy22 = Enemy2(400,100,90,40,white,"enemyplane2.png")

# For Coins

Coin1 = Coin(300,250,45,45,white)
Coin2 = Coin(300,350,45,45,white)

# For Enemy3
ememy31 = enemy3(400,400,90,40,white)


# For Enemy
enemys = [enemy1,enemy4]

#For Coin
coins = [Coin1,Coin2]

# enemys
enemyGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
level1 = [
"                        1    c    1        c   1              c         c            c                        ",
"      c                      1         1       1   c  1    c     1      1    1    1    1    1     1                            ",
"      c                   1        c        1               1      1    c            1        c         1   ",
"      c            1   c      1 c       1      1    1   c1      c 1   1    1 c  1    c    1     1  c             ",
"   c  c  c  c       1    1  c      1          c1         1    1                      1   1   c1     1  c  1    1  ",
"                   c          1      c    1            c            c   1  c  1  c          c    c                 ",
"                      1   1   c   1   1 c     1   c1     1   c 1    1      cc      1  c  1      1   c  1       ",]


for iy, row in enumerate(level1):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "1":
            new_enemy = Enemy(ix*70,iy*70,45,45,(255,255,255),"enemyplane1.png")
            enemys.append(new_enemy)
for iy, row in enumerate(level1):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "c":
            new_coins = Coin(ix*70,iy*70,45,45,(255,255,255))
            coins.append(new_coins)


enemy2Group = pygame.sprite.Group()
level2 = [
" ",
" ",
" ",
" ",
" ",
" ",
" ",]
for iy, row in enumerate(level2):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "2":
            new_enemy2 = Enemy2(ix*70,iy*70,90,40,(255,255,255),"enemyplane2.png")
            Enemy2.append(new_enemy2)

    

# Redrawwinodw
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    bg_width = bg.get_width()
    bg_offset = bg_shift % bg_width 
    
    window.blit(bg, (-bg_offset, 0)) 
    window.blit(bg, (bg_width - bg_offset, 0))

    
    # Draw playerman
    playerman.draw()

    # Draw enemy
    for enemy in enemys:
        enemy.draw()

    # Draw enemy2
    enemy21.draw()

    # Draw enemy3
    ememy31.draw()

    #Draw Coin
    for Coin in coins:
        Coin.draw()


    # Draw Enemy gun and playergun

    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(window)

    for egun in eguns:
        egun.draw(window)




    window.blit(text,textRect)
# FPS Cnd Clock
fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font  = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
score = 0
text = font.render("Coins = "+str(score),True,(0,0,0))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = ((100,40))

# For Bullets List And Timer
bullets = []

btimer = 0

# For Enemy Bullets And Timer
eguns = []

etimer = 0

# Main Loop
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    for Coin in coins:
        for one in range(len(coins)-1,-1,-1):
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(coins[one].rect):
                del coins[one]
                score += 1
                text = font.render("Coins = "+str(score),True,(0,0,0))
                textRect.center = ((100,40))

    for Coin in coins:
        Coin.x -= Coin.speed





    # Timer for Bullets
    if btimer > 0:
        btimer += 1
    if btimer > 10:
        btimer = 0

    # Timer for Enemy Bullets
    if etimer > 0:
        etimer += 1
    if etimer > 13:
        etimer = 0

# This Is Keys for bullet
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # This is bullets and when player press Spacebar they come
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < 700 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.speed 
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and btimer == 0:
        if len(bullets) < 5:
                bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2),round(playerman.y + playerman.height-24),(0,0,0)))

        btimer = 1




    # Timer for Enemy Bullets
    for enemy in enemys:
        if enemy.etimer > 0:
            enemy.etimer += 1
        if enemy.etimer > 40:
            enemy.etimer = 0

    for egun in eguns:
        if egun.x < 700 and egun.x > 0:
            egun.x -= egun.speed 
        else:
            eguns.pop(eguns.index(egun))
            
    for Enemy in enemys:
        if Enemy.x < 700 and Enemy.etimer == 0:
            if len(eguns) < 15:
                eguns.append(enemybullets(round(Enemy.x+Enemy.width//2),round(Enemy.y + Enemy.height-24),(0,0,0)))
            Enemy.etimer = 1


    for Enemy in enemys:
        Enemy.x -= Enemy.speed

    

    # For The Background Shifting
    bg_shift += round(3/2)


    # Keys For Playerman
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and playerman.x > playerman.speed:
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
       
        

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and playerman.x < 260 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed


    if keys[pygame.K_w] and playerman.y > playerman.speed:
        playerman.y -= playerman.speed


    if keys[pygame.K_s] and playerman.y < 500 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
        playerman.y += playerman.speed


            
# Update And Other Sutff    
    redrawwindow()


    
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  As the guidelines tell you, "Make it easy for others to help you."  You posted 400 lines of code, without doing any value or flow tracing, for a type of problem that is usually contained within 5-10 lines.

Comment: See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).  Put in some strategic `print` statements to trace your values and program flow.

Comment: The loop is using a temporary name of `Coin`, occluding the identical class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the coin class, you are setting local (temporary) variables for the coin position. You need to update the class\object rectangles.

Here is the updated code:

```
class Coin:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        ..........

    def draw(self):
        self.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        coin_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        #self.rect.centery -= 4  # move coins up ?
        self.rect.centerx -= 4  # move coins left
        window.blit(self.ss1,self.rect)
```